# Java accessing instance variables

Tags: java, static, static-methods

How can I make the object array named rooms accessible to the static method at the end called retrieveRoom(); I tryed public static Rooms rooms[] = new Rooms[3]. But I am just getting errors from that. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class MasterControlPanel{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Rooms rooms[] = new Rooms[3];

    rooms[0] = new Rooms("Room U", 1, 4, 4);
    rooms[1] = new Rooms("Room U", 2, 4, 4);
    rooms[2] = new Rooms("Connector X", 3, 2, 4);
    rooms[3] = new Rooms("Connector U", 4, 2, 4);

    for(int x = 0; x <= rooms.length; x++){
        rooms[x].createLights();
        rooms[x].createWalls();
    }
    }

    public static Object retrieveRoom(int connectedRoom){

    connectedRoom -= 1;
    return rooms[connectedRoom];
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move

```
public static Rooms[] rooms = new Rooms[4];
```

out of your `main()` method, to the declarations section like this

```
public class MasterControlPanel {
    public static Rooms[] rooms = new Rooms[4];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    }
}
```

This will define a `rooms` *static member* in your `MasterControlPanel` class.

Here are some other tips:

1. Static members can be accessed as long as that `Class` exists. However, in order to access instance members (variables which belong to an *instance* of that class) you need an instance of the class.
2. Use `Rooms[] rooms = new Rooms[4];`. Notice that array brackets are moved to `Type` part, this will prevent confusion in future. "*Let's define An Array of Rooms with the name rooms*". This is not required however a good thing to do.
3. You are defining `rooms` array with the size of **3** however you are adding **4** elements to it. This will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.
4. You should make your members `private` to achieve [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). You can provide `public` or `protected` methods to retrieve those `private` members from out of your class.
5. When an Array contains `n` elements, maximum number of consecutive iterations that you can make on that array is also `n` that's for sure. That means in a `for` loop make sure that your loop condition is `n-1` for the last iteration. Remember, there is no `4`th element in a size `4` array.

Here follows the code

```
public class MasterControlPanel {
    public static Room[] rooms = new Room[4];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        rooms[0] = new Room("Room U", 1, 4, 4);
        rooms[1] = new Room("Room U", 2, 4, 4);
        rooms[2] = new Room("Connector X", 3, 2, 4);
        rooms[3] = new Room("Connector U", 4, 2, 4);

        for (int x = 0; x <= rooms.length-1; x++) {
            rooms[x].createLights();
            rooms[x].createWalls();
        }
    }

    public static Room retrieveRoom(int connectedRoom) {
        connectedRoom -= 1;
        return rooms[connectedRoom];
    }

}

class Room {
    // These are instance members for Room class
    private String roomString;
    private int roomInteger1, roomInteger2, roomInteger3;

    public Room(String string, int integer1, int integer2, int integer3) {
        // This is the constructor for Room object
        this.roomString = string;
        this.roomInteger1 = integer1;
        this.roomInteger2 = integer2;
        this.roomInteger3 = integer3;
    }

    public void createLights() {
        // This method creates lights
    }

    public void createWalls() {
        // This method creates walls
    }

    // These are Getters and Setters for Room members
    public String getRoomString() {
        return roomString;
    }

    public void setRoomString(String roomString) {
        this.roomString = roomString;
    }

    public int getRoomInteger1() {
        return roomInteger1;
    }

    public void setRoomInteger1(int roomInteger1) {
        this.roomInteger1 = roomInteger1;
    }

    public int getRoomInteger2() {
        return roomInteger2;
    }

    public void setRoomInteger2(int roomInteger2) {
        this.roomInteger2 = roomInteger2;
    }

    public int getRoomInteger3() {
        return roomInteger3;
    }

    public void setRoomInteger3(int roomInteger3) {
        this.roomInteger3 = roomInteger3;
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable needs to be static to be accessible by a static method.

Comment: Member properties are not available to static methods without an instance; your edit does not address this--your code will not compile.

Comment: Now it does, although there's still a mic of the old and new code/verbiage in the answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for noticing. I tried to improve it after your comment.